# Toad for Oracle 10.6 versus 11.5: Performance Problems while editing large Packages

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, toad, utility

Actually I´m using Toad 10.6 to work with PL-SQL code. Now, our company is preparing to migrate to Toad 11.5, but, I noticed that large PL-SQL editing on 11.5 is so slow that makes impossible to me to work with that version.

Actually, a package file that contains about 1.4Mb of code takes ***5 seconds*** to load on Toad 10.5 and, the same time is spent when we use the 'Formatter Utility' to automatically format that file.

The **same** file, on Version 11.5, takes ***3.5 minutes*** to load, and the same time is spent when we try to format the document. During this times, the application is reported as 'Not Responding' in Windows TaskManager.

Does anybody knows how could I improve the performance on 11.5 version?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found that **Check Rule as you Type** option should be **disabled** to avoid the behavior that we was discussing.

To disable:

1. Open a Editor
2. Right Click on it
3. Search for **Analyze**
4. Uncheck **Check Rules as you Type**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Did you submit a support request to https://support.quest.com/?

I don't have any large source files to play around with. The largest package I have is about 200kb. I was able to open a 12mb .sql file with 43,000 lines of insert statements in ~20 seconds in 9.7 and ~40 seconds in 11.6.

I never had any luck with TOAD 10, I hated it, it crashed so often and used so much memory, so I stuck with 9.7 for a few years. More recently I've used 11.5 and 11.6 as well, with much better luck. All three are running side by side, and I can open them all simultaneously with no problems. Can you just keep both versions installed and open the large files in one and do everything else in the other?